# Java Object Mapper Deserialization Issue

Tags: java, object, serialization, objectmapper

I have a Java Object that I'm serializing and deserializing using Object mapper in Java.

Here's the Object details:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class SystemEvent extends Event {
    private static final long version = 4326410L;
    private SystemEventInfo systemEventInfo;
    private String message;

    @JsonCreator
    public SystemEvent(Identifier identifier) {
        super(identifier);
    }

    public SystemEventInfo getSystemEventInfo() {
        return this.systemEventInfo;
    }

    public void setSystemEventInfo(SystemEventInfo eventInformation) {
        this.systemEventInfo = eventInformation;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return this.msgId;
    }

    public void setMessage(String msgId) {
        this.msgId = msgId;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "MMSystemEvent{systemEventInfo=" + this.systemEventInfo + ", message='" + this.message + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

Here's my test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test {

    SystemEvent systemEvent;

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String msg = mapper.writeValueAsString(systemEvent);

        SystemEvent event = mapper.readValue(msg, SystemEvent.class);
        System.out.println(event);
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
         systemEvent = new SystemEvent(new Identifier());
         systemEvent.setMessage("msg123");
    }

}
```

Here's the result from the System print:

```
String msg = {"identifier":{"tenantId":"test","other props":false},"message":"msg123"}

Deserialized event = SystemEvent{systemEventInfo=null, message='null'}
```

Why does the object mapper map the message field to null?

Comment: It also maps the Identifier to null, isn‘t it?

Comment: No. The identifier is getting mapped correctly

Comment: What jackson version are you using? With jackson 2.13, I couldn't reproduce behaviour that you're facing. In my case it throws an UnrecognizedPropertyException. You can try to add @JsonProperty("identifier") to the identifier argument in SystemEvent's constructor and see if it helps. It might also be useful to add code for Event and Identifier classes to the question.